# Reference HTML input text from control

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to reference the value of the current control if it an input text?

```
foreach (Control c in line1.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText")
    {
        c.ID.Value() = "test";
    }
}
```

I have a HTML page and I want to loop through the controls, and set their value in the loop. Am I going about this all wrong? I can't find a way to reference the HTmlInputText from a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the Control with `is`

```
foreach (Control c in line1.Controls)
{
    //check if the control is a textbox
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        //cast it back to a textbox to access its properies
        TextBox tb = c as TextBox;
        tb.Text = "TextBox found";

        //or set the id
        c.ID = "test";
    }
}
```

Or a generic control

```
foreach (Control c in line1.Controls)
{
    //check if the control is a HtmlInputControl
    if (c is HtmlInputControl)
    {
        //cast it back to a HtmlInputControl to access its properies
        HtmlInputControl hic = c as HtmlInputControl;
        hic.Value = "HTML TextBox found";

        //or set the id
        c.ID = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Only trouble is, HtmlInputText is not a text box, and I get an error when I cast it as a "TextBox".

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: This works! I had to add the reference "using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;" to the top to get the HtmlInputControls to work. This seemed to be what I was missing.